# How get URL after using idhttp post

Tags: delphi, indy10, idhttp

I'm using idhttp to get content of a site.
After get the content, the site will change URL from www to www8 or www9 or www10, for example: www.sample.com is before posting, after posting it will be www10.sample.com. How to get it? Thank you.

Comment: You're probably looking for the `TIdHTTP.URL.Host` property.

Comment: @TLama: Can you also answer this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17705391/idhttp-post-session-expire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are encountering is likely an HTTP redirect.  `TIdHTTP` handles redirects automatically if its `HandleRedirects` property is set to True.  `TIdHTTP` has an `OnRedirect` event so you can get the new URL being redirected to, or you can look at the `TIdHTTP.Response.Location` property (which can also be filled in by some non-redirect responses as well, such as when uploading a file to Amazon S3 via `TIdHTTP.Put()`).