# Idhttp post session expire

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy, indy10

I'm using Idhttp (indy10 with delphi-xe2) to post form, but I get session expired message from the site, although I've already set cookie manager. Thank you.

```
procedure TForm2.IdCookieManager1NewCookie(ASender: TObject; ACookie: TIdCookie;
var VAccept: Boolean);
begin
  ShowMessage(Acookie.CookieText);
end;
```

The result from ShowMessage is: `ASP.NET_SessionId=enn1xnqde1o1rduedels5fqp; Path=/; Domain=www8.ticketingcentral.com; HttpOnly; Max-Age=252028195945; Expires=Fri, 31-Dec-9999 16:59:59 GMT`

Comment: Please show the **original** cookie as provided by the HTTP server, not `TIdCookie`'s interpretation of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When both `Max-Age` and `Expires` are present in a cookie, `Max-Age` takes priority and `Expires` is ignored, per RFC 6265.  `Max-Age` is expressed in seconds from the current clock time.  A `Max-Age` value of `252028195945` is ~7991 years in the future!  Adding that the current clock creates a date in the year 10004, which `TDateTime` cannot represent (9999 is the highest year it supports).  So you are likely getting a rounding issue with the expiration date being set to a negative value, thus representing a date in the past, not the future, thus expiring the cookie before it can ever be sent back to the HTTP server.